# How to combine return results of query in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a table that save personnel code.

When I select from this table I get 3 rows result such as:

```
2129,3394,3508,3534
2129,3508
4056
```

I want when create select result combine in one row such as:

```
2129,3394,3508,3534,2129,3508,4056
```

or distinct value such as:

```
2129,3394,3508,3534,4056
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ideally avoid storing CSV data at all in your tables.  That being said, for your first result set we can try using `STRING_AGG`:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(col, ',') AS output
FROM yourTable;
```

Your second requirement is more tricky, and we can try going through a table to remove duplicates:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT VALUE AS col
    FROM yourTable t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t.col, ',')
)

SELECT STRING_AGG(col, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CAST(col AS INT)) AS output
FROM cte;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + US.remain_uncompleted 
           FROM Table_request US
           WHERE exclusive = 0 AND reqact = 1 AND reqend = 0
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```

Thank you Tim

Comment: Why not use `STRING_AGG` as Tim suggests?

Comment: Since the tag says SQL-Server-2017, STRING_AGG is definitely the simpler way to achieve this. But any version prior to SQL-Server-2016 would require a different approach. And then this XML PATH in combination with STUFF approach comes handy.